# How to get comments using instagram API in java

Tags: java, api, instagram

I am doing an assignment for school where I need to make a script that gets comments off of Instagram and then uses SentiStrength. How would I get the comments? I don't know how to use "GET" in java and I don't know how to code in python.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm kinda sure you don't want the code that do what you need, you need to learn how to do things.

First you will need to check the API documentation and get your Api Key : https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Next you will need to implement the OAuth flow, a request to login with your credentials on Instagram using your client key.

This request will return a token, this token you'll need for make GET requests with your instagram user.

Check this site with information about create a simple client in Java

https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client

For future questions I suggest to make a research, try to code whatever and then formulate a specific question.